# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './*.scss'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I build a project with **React**, **TypeScript**, and **SCSS**. The project has got issue: **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './*.scss'** even I have created `declarations.d.ts` in `/src` but it's not work.

**`declarations.d.ts`**

```
declare module '*.scss';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If do you using npm and webpack

```
npm install --save-dev sass-loader sass webpack
npm install --save-dev @types/sass-loader @types/sass @types/webpack
```

If do you using yarn and webpack

```
yarn add sass-loader sass webpack --dev
yarn add @types/sass-loader @types/sass @types/webpack --dev
```

Comment: It's work. Thanh you so much :))

Comment: Hum, you can click green checkbox on the left to mark answer as correct. Thanks to it other people looking for unsolved questions can save time.